# TFS command line to get all mapping information of a specific workspace

Tags: tfs

I am trying get all maping information for a specific workspace.

When I try this command, it displays a dialog - which is not what I want.

```
tf workspace myworkspace
```

Is there a command that will get all the working folder information and output to the console?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following command displays the working folder mappings for the workspace in the current directory:

```
C:\projects>tf workfold
```

If you want to list the working folder mappings for a different workspace, you can specify the `/workspace:workspacename` parameter.

```
C:\>tf workfold /workspace:My_Other_Workspace
```

You can manipulate the workspace mappings using this command also.

The following example maps the folder `C:\DifferentWorkfold` to the Team Foundation version control server folder `$/projects/project_one`

```
c:\projects>tf workfold $/projects/project_one C:\DifferentWorkfold
```

See [Tf Command-Line Utility - Workfold Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fa04bx6.aspx) on MSDN for more information

Answer (score 1):

In TFS 2008 and TFS 2010, the command

```
C:\projects>tf workfold
```

would indeed display the working folder mappings for the workspace in the current directory.

However, for TFS 2012, this command no longer works.
Now, you just get an error message:

```
Unable to determine the workspace.  You may be able to correct this by 
running the command 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'
```

If I knew the TeamProjectCollectionUrl then I wouldn't need to run the `workfold` command!

Comment: You can use `tf workspaces` (without the collection param) to get the list of all workspace on the current computer for the current user